# Entity Framework Code First and Multiple Assemblies

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have a subclass in a different assembly to its base class. The parent is a POCO class used for EF Code First.

When I try to add an instance of inherited class to the database I get ***InvalidOperationException:*** *"Object mapping could not be found for Type with identity 'Foo.Bar.MyInheritedClass'".*

It works fine if subclass is in same assembly as base class.

In regular EF the [solution seems to be](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/df770006-43c1-4576-951f-1b2e396202a6) a call to **ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(assembly)**. But I can't figure out how this relates to Code First.

Any advice?

I'm using **Entity Framework 4.1 RC.**

Comment: Why can't you still call that function? 

I've not actuaqlly checked, but based on some quick searching you should be able to access the `MetadataWorkspace` from your `DbContext` using `dbContext.MetadatWorkspace`. Does that not work?

Comment: Yes, you can cast DbContext to IObjectContextAdapter and retrieve it's underlying ObjectContext (See: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/01/21/fix-wcf-data-service-with-entity-framework-code-first-dbcontext-doesn-t-accept-updates.aspx).

Comment: That allowed me to try MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly() but it didn't fix my problem :(

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by inheriting from the first assembliy's DbContext, adding a DbSet<> for the derived class, and then adding new instances of derived type to to that.

Posted code on MSDN forum [here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/20ea866c-38a1-4285-b682-075902ed9cae)

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a bit old, but I was able to accomplish this using @Dave's recomendation inside the constructor:

```
public Context() {
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(
             typeof(--[Inherited DbContext]--)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite new to EF (Entity Framework 4) and I got the same exception when I made changes in the model.

My problem turned out to be that I did not know EF need all the names on all the navigation properties to agree, not only their type. For example if there is a navigation property named foo, then there needs to be a declared variable in the corresponding class with the very same name.